# Any way to stop the Launcher from appearing when click-dragging a file?

Tags: unity, launcher

So when you click-drag a file, if the launcher is auto-hidden it'll appear for this, any way to stop that?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNDp0.jpg]

Just wondering, ubuntu13.10  unity 7.1.2

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Comment: looking around gconf and stuff, but not seeing anything...  it's no bigdeal at all, just idk..   is there an option to not exactly have "auto-hide" but have launcher hidden until you hold and press 'super' , and not ever show up otherwise, even when you mouse over?

Answer (score 1):

When you start dragging the file, the possible drop targets are automatically activated. Notice that the file manager, the drive and removable devices, and the trash are highlighted. This in turn causes the launcher to show itself.

To prevent this behavior, you would need to remove these icons from the launcher; but as far as I can tell, it is not possible to remove the trash icon.

So, no it is not possible to keep the launcher from showing itself when you drag files.